# jQuery .each() function - Which method is optimized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am retrieving the text value present inside the `<a>` elements using jQuery `.each()` function and storing it in a Array. I have found the below two methods and am not sure which i should prefer.

```
var textArr = [];

// Method 1
var textLinks = $("a").each(function(){
    textArr.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});


//Method 2
$("a").each(function(){
    textArr.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

What are the pros & cons of Method 1 and Method 2?

Comment: They are both identical, it's just in the first you assign the result of `$("a")` into a variable

Comment: Where is the difference?

Comment: Test it out: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: `$("a").each(function(k,v){
    textArr[k] = $.trim($(this).text());
});` should be a bit faster. You should definitely use `$.map` here.

Comment: *"Which method do you prefer?"* Stack Overflow isn't for surveys, it's for asking questions with specific answers. See the help for details.

Comment: @epascarello, Method 2 seems to be fastest than Method 1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), because it's there for this very purpose (no need for temp array)

```
var textLinks = $("a").map(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text());
});
```

Edit: If I was looking for the fastest solution I'd start with ditching jQuery ;)

```
var textLinks = (Array.prototype.slice.call(document.links)).map(function(a){ return a.textContent || a.innerText })
```

Or if you're concerned about browsers without `Array.map` use plain old while loop. Looks like a mess, but is FAST.

```
var textLinks = (function(links, out){ 
    var i = links.length, a; 
    while(a = links[--i]){ out[i] = a.textContent || a.innerText } 
    return out; 
}(document.links,[]))
```

[Added to jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/eachandother/2)

Comment: The above comment by jashwant seems faster than your post. [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/eachandother)

Comment: @Mr_Green I've used `map` as it clearly expresses intent of the code -  "make a new list with each element transformed according to these rules", while `each` means "do *something* to every element of the list".

Comment: +1 I learnt some more about JS from last approach :)